# How to access a variable outside a function?

Tags: javascript, html, select, global-variables

I have a select menue, an object and a function who gives me back the `selectedValue` as an array of the object. How can I access the `choosenArray` outside of the function?

I tried to declare the `choosenArray` as a global variable, but it does not work.
It only works for `"car1"`, because its selected first. Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<select id="list" onchange="getSelectValue();">
<option value ="car1">car1</option>
<option value ="car2">car2</option>
<option value ="car3">car3</option>
<option value ="car4">car4</option>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
  var carData = {
  "car1": [1, 5, 6, 7],
  "car2": [4, 6, 8, 3],
  "car3": [6, 7, 3, 4],
  "car4": [3, 7, 2, 1]
};

var choosenArray;
function getSelectValue() {
  selectedValue = document.getElementById("list").value;
  console.log(selectedValue);
  choosenArray = carData[selectedValue];
  console.log(choosenArray);
 return choosenArray;
}

var valueOfchoosenArray = getSelectValue(); //does not work for car2, car3, car4
console.log(valueOfchoosenArray); //does not work for car2, car3, car4
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your select in

```
<select id="list" onchange="useSelectValue()">
```

Then write a function:

```
var valueOfchoosenArray;
function useSelectValue() {
valueOfchoosenArray = getSelectValue();
console.log(valueOfchoosenArray);
//Do stuff
}
//You can use the value of valueOfchoosenArray here but code 
write here is not is executed when you change the select value
```